# C# WPF добавление данных в Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пишу приложение под windows phone, цель вывести данные в ListBox, делаю так:

```
myVM = new ObservableCollection<ParaModel>();
myVM.Add(currentWeek.Days[dayOfWeek].Pars[0]);
myVM.Add(currentWeek.Days[dayOfWeek].Pars[1]);
myVM.Add(currentWeek.Days[dayOfWeek].Pars[2]);
listData.ItemsSource = myVM;
```

в коллекции myVM с данными всё ок, в конечном объекте 2 строки, но listData.ItemsSource = myVM не србатывает

в xaml это выглядит так:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="listData" Margin="10,0,0,334">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Width="300" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding Caption}" />
                            <TextBlock Width="100" FontSize="40" Text="{Binding Audit}" TextAlignment="Right" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

объясните, плиз, что делаю не так..

Comment: Что значит «не срабатывает»? Ничего на экране не видно? А у вас место осталось для Item'ов? Попробуйте временно убрать `ItemTemplate` и посмотрите, что получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в ListBox нужно передавать коллекцию моделей с property, я же передавал fields((